# Non linear constraint python gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, gurobi, nonlinear-optimization

Is it possible to solve a constraint defined by the multiplication of two binary decision variables in python using Gurobi?

I need to have a constraint that limits the distance of a shop to the city block of its headquarter

x_ik --> decision variable set to 1 if shop i belongs to headquarter k

y_kc --> decision variable set to 1 if headquarter k is in city block c

d_ic --> distance between shop i and city block c

I've tried this but it tells me the model is infeasible:

```
for k in K:
    for c in C:
        for i in I:
            modelo.addConstr(x_ik[i, k] * y_kc[k[, c] * d_ic.at[i, c] <= 300, "c7")
```

The constraint I want to use is in the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jSeK.png)

Comment: Yes, Gurobi can handle quadratic constraints. This is non-convex, so you may see a message about using the NonConvex parameter,

Comment: Erwin is right. However, note that you can easily linearize the product of two binary variables, [see here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables). Thereby you keep the convexity, which in turn makes the problem easier to solve.

Comment: Gurobi may even linearize this automatically.